# BufferedReader.readLine() from a socket in Java stuck

Tags: java, sockets, resultset, readline, bufferedreader

I will try to explain my problem in detail. Feel free to ask if you need more details.

I have a multi-client/server connection threaded by Java sockets. All the exchanges operate according to the protocol on a simple case by case basis. The method searchFlight(destination,date) queries the the SQL database (sorry I can't provide it) and returns a ResultSet variable. And then, the method displaySelected(ResultSet) sends the ResultSet as a String to the client line by line.

The communication works well until the server sends the "Hour" to the client. I monitored the values on the server and it appears that the Server sends the correct String to the client (which is supposed to be "Flight hour (HH:MM):") but the client only prints the previous one. Concretely, it is stuck like this:

```
(1) Make reservation | (2) Cancel reservation
1
Choose the departure date (YYYY-MM-DD):
2012-01-01
(1) Go to Encampment | (2) Go to City:
2
+------|-----------|------------|-------------|----------|-------+  
| Code | Company   | Dest       | Date        | Hour     | Seats |  
+------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+  
| AER2 | Aerocamp  | City       | 2012-01-01  | 07:00:00 | 5 /6  |  
| COP2 | CopterFly | City       | 2012-01-01  | 09:00:00 | 5 /6  |  
| AER1 | Aerocamp  | City       | 2012-01-01  | 10:00:00 | 3 /6  |  
| H001 | HeliAir   | City       | 2012-01-01  | 11:00:00 | 6 /6  |  
| COP1 | CopterFly | City       | 2012-01-01  | 11:00:00 | 6 /6  |  
| AER2 | Aerocamp  | City       | 2012-01-01  | 13:00:00 | 4 /6  |  
| COP2 | CopterFly | City       | 2012-01-01  | 15:00:00 | 2 /6  |  
| AER1 | Aerocamp  | City       | 2012-01-01  | 16:00:00 | 6 /6  |  
| COP1 | CopterFly | City       | 2012-01-01  | 17:00:00 | 2 /6  |  
| COP3 | CopterFly | City       | 2012-01-01  | 20:00:00 | 3 /6  |  
+------|-----------|------------|-------------|----------|-------+  
Flight code (XXX#):
AER1
Flight code (XXX#):

Flight code (XXX#):
```

I am stuck with this problem for a couple of days now, and I really don't know how to fix it.
I have tried a lot of alternatives without success. I hope someone more experienced with Java than me could help me.

Thank you in advance.

You can see all my code bellow.

---

CLIENT SIDE

```
public class Client {

static Socket clientSocket = null;

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1024);
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host:");
            System.exit(1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;
        String fromClient = null;

        try {
            while (((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)) {

                System.out.println(fromServer);
                System.out.flush();     

                if(!fromServer.endsWith("  ")){
                    fromClient = stdIn.readLine();
                }

                if (fromClient != null) {
                    out.println(fromClient);
                    out.flush();
                }
                }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            stdIn.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue. On the client, when you're reading the flight/schedule list, for every line of **display only** data you read from the server, you're sending the previous input that the user entered to the server. That's the reason it keeps printing `City`, because the client keeps on sending `2` that it collected for the option `encampment or city`.

Replace

```
if(!fromServer.endsWith("  ")){
    fromClient = stdIn.readLine();
}
```

with

```
if(!fromServer.endsWith("  ")){
    fromClient = stdIn.readLine();
} else {
    // Data from the server is for display only. No input is required.
    // Clear out previous input.
    fromClient = null;
}
```

Apart from this, you need to handle the `Hour` input in your `Protocol.process(..)`